# Why does this question gives EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, eoferror

Chef is struggling to pass a certain college course.

The test has a total of NN question, each question carries 33 marks for a correct answer and −1−1 for an incorrect answer. Chef is a risk-averse person so he decided to attempt all the questions. It is known that Chef got XX questions correct and the rest of them incorrect. For Chef to pass the course he must score at least PP marks.

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    a=input().split()
    if int(a[1])*3-((int(a[0])-int(a[1]))*-1)>=int(a[2]):
        print('pass')
    else:
        print('fail')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 3, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing to provide required inputs. What sample inputs you tried?

Comment: Look at [handling an EOFException in Python](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-eoferror-exception-in-python/amp/).